# Build script not working with HTML5Boilerplate new download

Tags: html5boilerplate

My first problem was that, though the documentation warned the JDK was required, and though I set the bin directory to that of the JDK, tools.jar was being searched for in the JRE folder. This made no sense, but I copied the tools.jar file over and it got past that problem. The next problem I had was the build script failing due to a failure to find a main.css file. I'm on a Windows 7 machine, and this is what I did to attempt the build:

1. Downloaded WinAnt v7 and installed it, specifying the jdk1.7.0_04/bin folder when asked for a Java directory.
2. Downloaded and unpacked a brand new package from HTML5Boilerplate, keeping the extra comments and such.
3. Downloaded the build project, unpacked it, and dropped its contents into a build folder at the root of the HTML5Boilerplate folder.
4. Opened a command prompt, navigated to the build directory, and ran the ant command.

The only thing I could think of that was causing the JDK/JRE problem was that this is a 64-bit system. That's just a guess, but the copied file worked OK for now.

This process performs some of the work without complaint, creating intermediate and publish directories, but then fails out, saying that it can't find a main.css file to copy. I want to stress that I didn't make any modifications at all to the files, so I'm confused as to why the build script can't find a file I didn't remove or rename. In the config/default.properties file of the build folder, on lines 74 and 80, it hard-codes main.js and main.css as file names used. I'm not sure if those are supposed to be dynamically generated, or if they must be manually created and included in the project for the build script to run. If so, why doesn't the default structure downloaded from the website have them? If they're dynamically created, I need advice on what is going wrong.

I'd really like to get this up and running so I can get started using HTML5Boilerplate, but I'm a little lost here.

-edit

After renaming the styles.css file to main.css, the build completed correctly, but the resulting files aren't correct. I read that the script would update the html file references to css and javascript files, but it didn't. For instance, I ended up with e68668b.css after the script ran, but the html file still referenced styles.css. Same for the javascript file. Help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The build script is now a separate project, which I downloaded from github. I downloaded the HTML5Boilerplate zip file from the HTML5Boilerplate website, which unfortunately still has the old folder structure. I went to github and downloaded the HTML5Boilerplate template there, and that made the difference.

[The HTML5Boilerplate website's link points to github's 3.0.2 version](http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/zipball/v3.0.2)

[The github's link points to version 3.0.2-69](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/)

And that's all she wrote. The names of some files changes, as well as some of the folder structure, between these two versions, and the build script I downloaded referenced the newest structures.